# Two Separate getTime() Calls Return Same Value at Different Times

Tags: java, android, date, time

I am making an app that saves when the user enters a location and exits. I have to separate `Date` objects for this. When I print out the values, they return the same exact time although they are saved at a different time. Any ideas what may be causing this?

My **checkLocation()** method:

```
private void checkLocation() {
            float[] distance = new float[2];
            for(int i = 1; i <= AssetLoader.getTotalLocations(); i++) {
                float mItemLat = AssetLoader.getItemLatitude(String.valueOf(i));
                float mItemLong = AssetLoader.getItemLongitude(String.valueOf(i));

                Location.distanceBetween(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(),
                        mItemLat, mItemLong, distance);

                if(distance[0] > 55){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Outside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " radius: " + "55", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(startDate != null) {
                        stopDate = calendar.getTime();
                        Log.e("STOP DATE", "SAVED");
                        saveTimeDifference(startDate, stopDate, String.valueOf(i));
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside, distance from center: " + distance[0] + " radius: " + "55", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(startDate == null) {
                        startDate = calendar.getTime();
                        Log.e("START DATE", "SAVED");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Where time difference and other stuff gets calculated:

```
public static void saveTimeDifference(Date startDate, Date endDate, String id) {
        //TODO: FIX THIS

        //milliseconds
        long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        AssetLoader.setItemTimeDifference(id, difference);

        System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
        System.out.println("endDate : "+ endDate);
        System.out.println("difference : " + difference);

        long secondsInMilli = 1000;
        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
        long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

        long elapsedDays = difference / daysInMilli;
        difference = difference % daysInMilli;

        long elapsedHours = difference / hoursInMilli;
        difference = difference % hoursInMilli;

        long elapsedMinutes = difference / minutesInMilli;
        difference = difference % minutesInMilli;

        long elapsedSeconds = difference / secondsInMilli;

        Log.e("saveTimeDifference()", elapsedDays + " days, " + elapsedHours + " hours, " + elapsedMinutes + " minutes, " + elapsedSeconds + " seconds");

        AssetLoader.setItemDetails(AssetLoader.getItemName(String.valueOf(id)), AssetLoader.getItemDetails(AssetLoader.getItemName(String.valueOf(id))) + "\nStart Date: " + startDate + " Stop Date: " + startDate);

    }
```

Please note that **the current time is being accessed at different times**. It seems to save it wrong or return the wrong time when getTime() is called on the GregorianCalendar object.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you show the initialization of the calendar object

Comment: `private Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());`

Comment: So that's a field, with a long life-span, and it never gets updated. See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`calendar.getTime()` returns a `java.util.Date` object for the time currently stored in the `Calendar` object.

When a `Calendar` is initially obtained by calling [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29) (or other means), it has the "current time".

It will still have that same time 5 hours later. It is not a "live" time, so multiple calls to `calendar.getTime()` will get the same value.

If you want to capture the current time, just call [`new Date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28%29):

```
Date startDate = new Date();
// do work
Date stopDate = new Date();
long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
System.out.println("Work took " + difference + "ms");
```

Comment: in OP's perspective, it might be simpler to use System.currentTimeMillis(); to get a timestamp of the current time.

Comment: @Gauthier True, but the current code has `startDate` and `stopDate` as fields of type `Date`, so I just stayed with that. The `Date` object does help debugging by providing (relatively) nice `toString()` output, e.g. for those `println()` calls OP has.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This gave me the correct time.

Answer (score 4):

The [accepted Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494243/642706) is correct.

## java.time

If you are doing more date-time work, consider using the new java.time framework which supplants the troublesome old date-time classes.

### UTC

To get the current moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

## Immutable objects

The classes in java.time use the [Immutable Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. Each instance’s values never change (never “mutate”). So when you want to know the current moment again, call `Instant.now` again to create another instance of `Instant`.

### Resolution

In Java 8 that current moment is captured with a resolution up to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), rather than the class’ capability of handling [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). This limitation is due to the use of a legacy implementation of [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html). In Java 9 a new implementation of `Clock` captures the current moment in up to the full nanosecond resolution depending on your computer’s hardware clock.

### Zoned

While it is generally best to store date-time values in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), for presentation you may want to display the values in a time zone expected by the user.

To adjust that [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) into a particular [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)). Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 letter abbreviations like `EST` or `IST`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( now , zoneId );
```

## Elapsed

To track an elapsed span of time in terms of days-hours-minutes-seconds, use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. As a textual representation, this class parses and generates Strings using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats such as `PT1H30M` for one and a half hours.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( startInstant , stopInstant );
String output = duration.toString();
```

You can get the total number of nanoseconds or seconds or minutes or hours or days in this span of time.

Oddly, the `Duration` class in Java 8 lacks methods to conveniently interrogate for the days part, hours part, minutes part, and seconds part. [Java 9 brings such methods](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142936).

For spans of time in years-months-days, use the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for the added information. It helped me a bunch!